# Visual Studio 2015 CSS Intellisense Broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Editing cshtml files, I'm used to getting Bootstrap intellisense, regardless of what classes I've already used in said file, like so:

[image: when things work]

Originally, I thought it was just Bootstrap intellisense, but it appears that this is affecting all CSS for my new project. I can link to the CSS files, directly reference the layout file, it doesn't matter. The Bootstrap and other CSS classes do not show, unless I've already used them in the same file:

[image: when it doesnt work]

I've tried to minimize the differences between the two projects, but to no avail. They are on different machines, in different solutions, but everything else is virtually exactly the same. Here's what I've checked/tried so far.

- Delete the project, re-add it.
- Remove the Bootstrap Nuget package re-add it
- Remove the Bootstrap Snippet Pack, Glyphfriend, Web Essentials 2015.2 extensions, re-add them.
- Delete the bin and obj folders, build, clean, rebuild, close/reopen VS, restart Windows.
- Deleted this folder to allow for recreation: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
- Both machines are running VS 2015 Update 2.
- Both projects are MVC 5.
- Installed all updates possible in Nuget Package Manager

Known differences
 - The machine it works on is running Windows 7, the machine it doesn't is running Windows 10.

Comment: did you get this sorted? I'm experiencing the same issue now...

Comment: negative. I think I'll have to open a ticket with MS if we're ever going to get an answer. If you open one yourself, let me know the ticket number so I can upvote it.

Comment: I managed to get it working by installing bootstrap using bower (this was in a .net core project btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this problem again and found a solution! I'm not sure if it's the same as the original problem I had, but here's the fix anyway.

If the solution has a SQL project (.dbproj), unload it (right click > unload project). There's some weird bug in VS2015 with Bootstrap and SQL database projects that make intellisense for Bootstrap stop working.

Comment: WOW, this helped me as well in Visual Studio 2017.  Strange conflict

Answer (score -2):

In order to get "Class" IntelliSense in VS 2015, try this method. It works for me as follows:

Ex: Right click on any .aspx file in "Solution Explorer" of VS then select "Open With" option then from the list select "HTML Editor" option. Now try to check.

Thanks
Ali